# GlDatePicker - why does calendar disappear when changing month?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using glDatePicker:
http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/

When I click on the button for next month, the calendar suddenly disappears. The css of the calendar changes to ‘`display:none`’.

Why does this occur, and how can *i* prevent this?
I have set the setting: ‘`showAlways: true`’

This is an extract of the code:

```
$('.datearrival').glDatePicker(
{
    showAlways: true,
    onClick: function(target, cell, date, data) {
        setInternationalDate ("#avfarr", target, date);
        setTimeout(showcalendar, 25);                
        if(data != null) {
            alert(data.message + '\n' + date);
        }
    }         

}); //end of datepicker.



<div id="arrivaldatecalendar" class="arrivaldatecalendar calendarcommon" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:0px; left:125px;width:320px !important; height:200px;" gldp-el="avfarr">
</div>

<input gldp-id="avfarr" type='text' name='arrival_date'  title='Ankunft' tabindex=1  class='datearrival' id='avfarr'></div>
```

Here is a link: http://www.rheinriverguesthouse.com/base7/en/welcome/index.php

Comment: Try to add on  jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I made some changes to glDatepicker.js ,e.g. changing this call to:

    onHide: function(calendar) { calendar.show(); },

Now it is working..